# What kernel options is Google's Container Optimized OS built with?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I'm having trouble finding the kernel options that Google's Container Optimized OS is built with. I tried looking at the usual locations like `boot/config-*` and `/proc/config.gz`, but didn't find anything. I searched the source code and didn't find anything either, but I'm probably just searching wrong.

The specific option I'm curious about is CONFIG_CFS_BANDWIDTH and whether it is enabled or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it via running `zcat /proc/config.gz` in a Container-optimized OS VM.

The kernel config is generated from the source [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/overlays/board-overlays/+/refs/heads/master/overlay-lakitu/sys-kernel/lakitu-kernel-4_14/files/base.config). However, note that the source kernel config are changed during the OS image building process. So they are not 100% the same.